# Ask permission to read user's email Graph API in android

Tags: android, email, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I want to ask permission to read users email id in Facebook using graph api.

I tried this

```
  graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email
```

I don't know how to ask permission via Graph API to read email.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need an `access_token` with the `email` permission.

Your syntax is wrong too. It's `fields=email`.

Comment: Is it possible to ask permission for email using graph api

Comment: Yes. You need to request this in your `scope` when you authenticate the user.